# Including and excluding directories for gerrit trigger in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, jenkins-groovy

I`ve got repository named REP in contains parent directory DIR1 and 3 sub directories, DIR1_1,DIR1_2 and DIR1_3. I need jenkins be triggered on Changes from DIR1_1 and DIR1_2 but not from DIR1_3.

Following what I found I tried that syntax (that is wrong)

```
[branches: [[compareType: 'PLAIN', pattern: 'dev']],  compareType: 'PLAIN', pattern: 'REP',File:[path: '/DIR1_1/**','/DIR1_2/**'],ForbiddenFile[path:'/DIR1_3/**']]
```

What is the right syntax ?
I need both option to include and to exclude directories from the trigger.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using declarative or scripted Jenkinsfile with your pipelines? I'm trying to import multiple projects from Gerrit in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is worked for me:

```
gerritProjects: [[
                    compareType: 'PLAIN',
                    pattern: 'REP',
                    disableStrictForbiddenFileVerification: 'false',
                    branches: [[
                                  compareType: 'PLAIN',
                                  pattern: 'dev'
                              ]],
                    filePaths: [[
                              compareType: 'ANT',
                              pattern: '/DIR1_1/**'
                          ]],
                    forbiddenFilePaths: [[
                                       compareType: 'ANT',
                                       pattern: '/DIR1_3/**'
                                   ]]
                ]]
```